# Library Package Manager does not appear

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I installed ASP MVC 3, but when I go to tools I can't see the Library Package Manager, it was supposed to install along ASP MVC 3, how come I cannot see it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem and NuGet Package Manager was showing as installed.

I opened a project, went to Tools, Extension manager, went to Tools, highlighted NuGet Package Manager, uninstalled.

Restarted (had the problem with both VS2010 & VS2012)

Went to Tools, Extension Manager, Online Gallery, found NuGet Package Manager, download, install, restart.

I then had the Library Package Manager where it should be.

Comment: Wow - Wasn't expecting it to, but this worked for me.  Thanks @Aaron .. MS is really headed downhill atm

Answer (score 7):

You need to install the [NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/) extension.  NuGet provides the package manager window and the right-click Add Library Package Reference menu extension.

Comment: I have downloaded Nuget for visual studio 2010 but I am getting error "This extension is not installable on any of the installed products". How to remove this error?

Answer (score 4):

Have you VS 2012? if that's the case, i think int not necessary Library Package Manager menu, if you want to see the command prompt PM> and install a new package, all you have to do is select Tools->NuGet Package Manager->Package Manager Console this action will show the Command Promt ready for install any package.

Comment: Thank you Luis! This is exactly where it was hidden for me.

Answer (score 2):

For `Library Package Manager` go through the following link, then you can get that.
  The link is http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget#Installing_NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is installed with MVC3 - it is in SP1? Or get the separate NuGet install?

Answer (score 0):

A quicker option in VS2012 may be to use the Tools / Import Export Settings menu.  In my case I had installed settings for Lightswitch which had very few Tools enabled in the Tools menu. I reset my Settings to the Web Development and all good - no restarting or reinstalling needed.

Answer (score 0):

This may be happen due to Library package not installed properly.

Just uninstall the NuGet through Extention Manager(Tools --> Extention Manager), and reinstall NuGet again.

https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet/wiki/Using-Nuget-in-Visual-Studio-2010-&-2012

Answer (score 0):

For Visual studio 2010, you can download the nugget package manager console:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c

Answer (score 0):

In my case, "Nuget Package Manager" was already installed but not updated and therefore it was not appearing under the "Tools" menu.

I follow these steps:

Open Visual Studio 2012 > Go to "Tools" > "Extensions and Updates" > "Updates" > "Visual Studio Gallery" > "Update NuGet Package Manager" > I Download and install it and then it ask for the restart.

After restarting, "NuGet Package Manager" appeared under the "Tools" Menu.

It worked for me...!!!